# Como resolver este error de sintaxis en la consulta?

Tags: postgresql, python-3.7

```py
import psycopg

conexion = psycopg.connect( user='postgres',password='admin',port='5432')
try:
    with conexion:
        with conexion.cursor() as cursor:
            sentencia = 'DELETE FROM personap WHERE id_persona IN %s'
            entrada = input('Proporciona los id_persona a eliminar (separados por coma): ')
            valores = (tuple(entrada.split(',')),)
            cursor.execute(sentencia,valores)
            #conexion.commit()
            registros_eliminados = cursor.rowcount
            print(f'Registros Eliminados: {registros_eliminados}')

except Exception as e:
    print(f'Ocurrio un error: {e}')
finally:
      conexion.close()
```

**Error**

```
C:\Cursos\Python\DB\Leccion01\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Cursos/Python/DB/Leccion01/data_test.py
Proporciona los id_persona a eliminar (separados por coma): 4,5
Ocurrio un error: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «$1»
LINE 1: DELETE FROM personap WHERE id_persona IN $1
                                                 ^

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Tal vez puedes probar con `cursor.execute(sentencia,(valores,))`

Comment: Trate, pero me sigue saltando el mismo error :(

Answer (score 3):

El error está al enviar tu sentencias SQL  `sentencia = 'DELETE FROM personap WHERE id_persona IN %s'` no puede ir `%s` de esta manera debes agregar paréntesis al operador IN algo de esta manera  `sentencia = 'DELETE FROM personap WHERE id_persona IN (%s)'`

ya en este caso no necesitarías utilizar tuple para reemplazar los valores, únicamente pasas los id separados por coma que capturas desde tu entrada para que quede de la siguiente manera

```
cursor.execute(sentencia,entrada)
```

[image: Resultado en consola del código python]

De esta manera es como quedaría cuando se le realiza el String Formatting a tu sentencia

Comment: sentencia = 'DELETE FROM personap WHERE id_persona IN ('%s') 
 'C:\Cursos\Python\DB\Leccion01\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Cursos/Python/DB/Leccion01/data_test.py
  File "C:\Cursos\Python\DB\Leccion01\data_test.py", line 9
    sentencia = sentencia = 'DELETE FROM personap WHERE id_persona IN ('%s')'
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Lo siento `%s` en tu variable sentencia va sin comillas simples, como lo acabo de corregir en la respuesta